# D3: Substituting d3.svg.diagonal() with d3.svg.line()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, circle-pack

I have implemented the following graph with the edges rendered with d3.svg.diagonal(). However, when I try substituting the diagonal with d3.svg.line(), it doesn't appear to pull the target and source data. What am I missing? Is there something I don't understand about d3.svg.line?

[image]

The following is the code I am referring to, followed by the full code:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.lx; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.ly; });
```

...

```
var link= svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(links)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d",d3.svg.diagonal())
    .attr("class", ".link")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("shape-rendering", "auto")
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

The entire code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width =1500, 
    height = 1500, 
    diameter = Math.min(width, height),
    radius = diameter / 2;


var balloon = d3.layout.balloon()
  .size([width, height])
  .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .gap(50)                  

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.lx; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.ly; });


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + radius) + "," + (margin.top + radius) + ")")

    root = "flare.json";
    root.y0 = height / 2;
    root.x0 = width / 2;

d3.json("flare.json", function(root) {
  var nodes = balloon.nodes(root),
      links = balloon.links(nodes);


var link= svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(links)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d",d3.svg.diagonal())
    .attr("class", ".link")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("shape-rendering", "auto")
    .attr("fill", "none");   

  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x })
      .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.y })
      .attr("font-size", "5px")
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "middle" : "middle"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
});
```

A comparison of how the d attribute of the svg disappears when using "line."
[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't seem to be using `line` anywhere in the code. The `d` attribute of the path is still set using `d3.svg.diagonal`.

Comment: Yes, but when I substitute "line" for "d3.svg.diagonal()"0 it breaks the vis. Can't figure out why.

Comment: The d attribute for the svg disappears. I will upload a comparison above.

Comment: Have you tried just `d3.svg.line()` without the custom accessors for `x` and `y`?

Comment: Have you got a JSFiddle or similar to look at?

Comment: @JakubSvec Can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002241/how-to-combine-force-layout-and-packed-layout-in-d3 ?

Answer (score 23):

Question is quite dated, but since I don't see an answer and someone might face the same problem, here it is.

The reason why simple replacement of *diagonal* with *line* is not working is because *d3.svg.line* and *d3.svg.diagonal* return different results:

- *d3.svg.diagonal* returns function that accepts datum and its index and transforms it to path using *projection*. In other words *diagonal.projection* determines how the function will get points' coordinates from supplied datum.
- *d3.svg.line* returns function that accepts an array of points of the line and transforms it to path. Methods *line.x* and *line.y* determine how coordinates of the point retreived from the single element of supplied array

[D3 SVG-Shapes reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes)

[SVG Paths and D3.js](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js)

So you can not use result of the *d3.svg.line* directly in d3 selections (at least when you want to draw multiple lines).

You need to wrap it in another function like this:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
                 .x( function(point) { return point.lx; })
                 .y( function(point) { return point.ly; });

function lineData(d){
    // i'm assuming here that supplied datum 
    // is a link between 'source' and 'target'
    var points = [
        {lx: d.source.x, ly: d.source.y},
        {lx: d.target.x, ly: d.target.y}
    ];
    return line(points);
}

// usage:
var link= svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d",lineData)
    .attr("class", ".link")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("shape-rendering", "auto")
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

Here's working version of jsFiddle *mobeets* posted: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xrU7/)

Comment: I think that
`.attr("d", function (d) { return line([ {lx: d.target.x, ly: d.target.y},{lx: d.source.x, ly: d.source.y} ]); });`
is a better way to do it instead of wrap `line()` in a global function.

Comment: Extra points for providing a drop-in replacement for `diagonal` for this context, elusive-code, rather than providing an alternative solution.  It's more than a year and a half later, and as you said, "someone might face the same problem" (me).   I hadn't found this solution in such a simple form anywhere else, and there are sure to be a number of people who want it some day.

Comment: @elusive-code Can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002241/how-to-combine-force-layout-and-packed-layout-in-d3 ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem...There's a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qsEbd/30/).

Note that changing `line` to `diagonal` will make it work.

Comment: My suggestion would be to post the code from jsFiddle here as it is not always reliable and up.  Then the specific answer will be available in this answer without having to go to an outside website.

Comment: @mobeets You've to pass the correct input to `line()`. You can do this wrap `line()` on another function as recomend @elusive-code or return to `line()` the correct input values like you can see on [my mod of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsEbd/213/).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps encapsulating the diagonal function and editing its parameters could work for you:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal();
var new_diagonal = function (obj, a, b) {
    //Here you may change the reference a bit.
    var nobj = {
        source : {
            x: obj.source.x,
            y: obj.source.y
        },
        target : {
            x: obj.target.x,
            y: obj.target.y
        }
    }
    return diagonal.apply(this, [nobj, a, b]);
}
var link= svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d",new_diagonal)
    .attr("class", ".link")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("shape-rendering", "auto")
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `d` attribute of link to line:

```
.attr("d", line)
```

Comment: Yes, but when I substitute "line" for "d3.svg.diagonal()"0 it breaks the vis.

Comment: Can you create a small example on jsFiddle?

Comment: I have tried, but the source code with the balloon layout is on github and it doesn't seem to be accepting it.