# Extending d3js hierarchical tree for representing topology

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

We want to use d3js hierarchical tree for representing topology. 
The features that we are looking for are:

1. Peer to peer linking
2. Child with 2 parents
3. Link between two objects represented as straight line instead of default curves.

These features are not supported by default, has anybody modified the D3js code to support any of the above mentioned features? Or is aware of any wrapper library which can be used?

Suggestion of any other library which support above feature will also help.

Attaching image for refrence[image]

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/MetalMonkey/JnNwu/

```
var json = 
{
    "name": "Base",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Type A",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section 1",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Section 2",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Type B",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section 1",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Section 2",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var width = 700;
var height = 650;
var maxLabel = 150;
var duration = 500;
var radius = 5;

var i = 0;
var root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + maxLabel + ",0)");

root = json;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

root.children.forEach(collapse);

function update(source) 
{
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
    var links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * maxLabel; });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d){ 
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i); 
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 0)
        .style("fill", function(d){ 
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "white"; 
        });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d){ 
            var spacing = computeRadius(d) + 5;
            return d.children || d._children ? -spacing : spacing; 
        })
        .attr("dy", "3")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d){ return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d){ return d.name; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d){ return computeRadius(d); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 0);
    nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d){ return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d){
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

function computeRadius(d)
{
    if(d.children || d._children) return radius + (radius * nbEndNodes(d) / 10);
    else return radius;
}

function nbEndNodes(n)
{
    nb = 0;    
    if(n.children){
        n.children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else if(n._children){
        n._children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else nb++;

    return nb;
}

function click(d)
{
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } 
    else{
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

function collapse(d){
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

update(root);
```

I need to draw edge between Type A and Type B node which are at same level

Comment: [cola.js](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/) may be suitable for this.

Comment: Just my 2 cents - do not to modify the code but extend it if possible instead.

Comment: Can you please attach a fiddle of what you have done. That could be helpful.

Comment: This sounds more like a graph to me than a tree. Perhaps look at some of the force directed graph examples?

Comment: Try to do something like that http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJrRVz?editors=011 (based on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1138500). A tree by definition is hierarchical, it's better to use the force layout to represent this graph.

Answer (score 4):

It has already been answered here : [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070150/d3-substituting-d3-svg-diagonal-with-d3-svg-line).

The only difference is the way you handle X versus Y positions. You have to declare :

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
                 .x( function(point) { return point.ly; })
                 .y( function(point) { return point.lx; });

function lineData(d){
    var points = [
        {lx: d.source.x, ly: d.source.y},
        {lx: d.target.x, ly: d.target.y}
    ];
    return line(points);
}
```

Please pay attention to the invertion of X and Y in `line` function declaration.
Then in your code (in `attr('d')` calls) instead of using `diagonal` just use `lineData`.